# Insert Citation dialog comes up empty

Tags: citation-management

I'm using Mathematica 10 with Endnote X5 on Windows 7. When I click on "Insert> Citation> Bibliographic Reference" command (while the cursor in Mathematica is in 'text' style mode, Alt+7) Endnote launches with the library populated with latest entries but the "Insert Citation" Dialog box remains empty despite attempts at refreshing. As a result I am unable to insert any citations into my Mathematcia notebook. Please Advise.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Have you tried opening EndNote beforehand, rather than having *Mathematica* open it for you? Also, have you tried hitting the "refresh library" button on the top right of the insert citation dialog in MMA? I have just tried the process with EndNote X7 and MMA 10.1 on Win7, and it works.

Comment: Thankyou MarcoB for taking the time to respond. Unfortunately your suggested approach doesnt work with me. I've also tried other simplistic solutions like rebooting the system, incase it was one of those windows problems.